# Kann man "wohin soll mein Lebensweg führen?" sagen?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

Ist der Satz "Wohin soll mein Lebensweg führen?" richtig oder klingt es ganz seltsam? Vielen dank im Voraus.

Comment: Das kann man so sagen. Für eine Antwort wäre es aber noch hilfreich zu wissen, wieso du der Ansicht bist, dass man es nicht sagen kann oder warum es deiner Ansicht nach seltsam klingt.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it contains no indication whatsoever as to what the asker doesn’t understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohne Kontext ist das für mich nicht gut zu beantworten. Die Frage kann z.B. heißen:

> Wie wird mein Leben wohl verlaufen?
>
> Was werde ich unterwegs alles erleben?
>
> Welchen Weg soll ich in meinem Leben einschlagen? (= Wofür soll ich mich entscheiden?)
>
> Was möchte ich in meinem Leben erleben?
>
> Was möchte ich in meinem Leben erreichen?
>
> Welche Orte möchte ich in meinem Leben unbedingt besucht haben?

Praktisch alle Wörter der Frage sind mehrdeutig und metaphorisch oder gegenständlich interpretierbar. Außerdem kann 'soll' futurisch oder imperativisch verstanden werden. Vielleicht sind diese Mehrdeutigkeiten beabsichtigt.

Ganz unabhängig von all dem finde ich persönlich den Satz nicht 'schön'. Ich hätte zumindest ein 'mich' hinzugesetzt und/oder auf das 'soll' und den 'Weg' verzichtet:

> Wohin führt mich das Leben?

Wahrscheinlich gibt es elegantere Möglichkeiten, aber dazu müsste die gewünschte Aussage bekannt sein.

Answer (score 2):

Dein Satz ist richtig, ist aber eher gehobene Schriftsprache und würde im Kontext der gesprochenen Alltagssprache geschwollen klingen. Da würde man es beispielsweise so sagen:

> Was soll / will ich aus meinem Leben machen?